# Javascript Unique Array for each Socket User

Tags: javascript, websocket

i have a Problem!

When two users playing a game and they click very near at the same time, all two users get what only the 2nd user must get.

Is it possible to make an array by his userid or something?

I also have for anti spam like that

```
anti_spam[socket.request.session.passport.user.id]
```

But thats a json

If i try the same or array, i get error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

How can i make sure, that each user get only his own items and not items from another user when opening at the same time?

I use sockets, here is a unique userid `socket.request.session.passport.user.id`

This is the array

```
var WinItem = [];
```

And if two users start like milliseconds same time, than the second overwrite the first...

Comment: Can you provide some additional information? Like where are you initializing WinItems?  Keep in mind we can't see the code of your program so you have a much greater insight and understanding of the structure and flow than we do.

Answer (score 0):

**! CODE NOT TESTED!**

Wait wait wait wait...

So I only know `ws (Node.js)` but there you first get a `onConnection` event.
In that function you add a UID to the connection element. Then if you receive a message from the client you should have you're connection object and therefore an UID. You now can store the won item in the connection object (if you want) maybe like so:

```
ws.onConnection = con => {
    con.UID = generateUID();
    con.inventory = [];
    con.onMessage = msg => {
        [..STUFF/CODE/YAY...]
        con.inventory.push(item);
        con.send("You've won wooohoo");
    });
});
```

Did you mean something like this??
Otherwise please be more specific about what you want.
(You can also store the stuff somewhere else together with the UID but that would add quiet some code)